# how to not get stretched pics when viewing them with shotwell

Tags: 12.04, shotwell

i use shotwell to organize my picture. I use it also crop and modify them. 
 Now that i have installed ubuntu 12.04 a crop picture is "stretched" so that it occupies the all screen. it used to keep the ratio between x and y in 11.10

any solution?

thanks,

dodohjk

Comment: this happen if i crop the original file of the picture. Does not happen if i crop it thru the shotwell (witch does not actually modify the original)

Comment: For me it sounds like a bug. http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Answer (score 0):

I work on the Shotwell project, and this does indeed sound like a bug, and, if possible, we'd like to know how it happens so we can fix it for you.

Based on your initial post, it looks like you're opening the image directly, rather than importing it.  Unfortunately, I'm not seeing any unusual behaviour when I crop an image in direct-edit mode - can you tell us more about what problems you're encountering?